# Hibernate не видит диалект и не определяет его автоматически

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, hibernate

Hibernate не видит диалект при указании его вручную и не определяет его автоматически. То есть я пробовал и указывать диалект в `application.properties`, и убирать его. Скажите, если надо выложить что-то еще.

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ru.terentyev</groupId>
    <artifactId>EffectiveMobile</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>EffectiveMobile</name>
    <description>Test task for Effective Mobile</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>20</java.version>
        <spring.version>3.2.0</spring.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
             <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
             </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
         <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
         <version>4.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.15.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate6</artifactId>
    <version>2.15.3</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

application.properties:

```
#spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration

#spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/effective_mobile
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres

hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/effective_mobile

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect

server.port=8080

spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity5.enabled=true
spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true

#show sql statement
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug

#show sql values
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace

logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=trace

spring.mvc.format.date=dd-MM-yyyy
spring.mvc.format.date-time=dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss
spring.mvc.format.time=HH:mm:ss

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

spring.jackson.serialization.indent_output=true
```

stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url' for common cases or 'hibernate.dialect' when a custom Dialect implementation must be provided)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:191) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentWithDefaults(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentUsingJdbcMetadata(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:348) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:130) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    ... 81 common frames omitted
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78036592/why-cant-spring-boot-deduce-hibernate-dialect

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!! Сейчас посмотрю...